# Локальная база Microsoft Access

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, access

У меня есть программа для учета, не знаю на чем написана, подключена к локальной базе Microsoft Access, она связана с другим компом по локальной сети. 
Могу ли я как то подключить эту базу к сайту с помощью php либо связать с MySQL?

Comment: Можете, через ODBC. [Пример связи](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807081/how-to-connect-php-with-microsoft-access-database) с файлом в PHP на англоязычном SO.

Answer (score 0):

PHP не поддерживает напрямую работу с Access. Но, через ODBC можно.

```
<?php
$bits = 8 * PHP_INT_SIZE;
echo "(Info: This script is running as $bits-bit.)\r\n\r\n";

$connStr = 
        'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
        'Dbq=C:\\Users\\Gord\\Desktop\\foo.accdb;';

$dbh = new PDO($connStr);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 
        "SELECT AgentName FROM Agents " .
        "WHERE ID < ? AND AgentName <> ?";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

// query parameter value(s)
$params = array(
        5,
        'Homer'
        );

$sth->execute($params);

while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    echo $row['AgentName'] . "\r\n";
}
```

Пример не мой. Взял [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807081/how-to-connect-php-with-microsoft-access-database).

Comment: А если база локально, а сайт на хосте, как правильно путь указать?

Comment: Расшариваете файл по сети и указываете его сетевой путь. По идее должно заработать. Но, по-хорошему лучше перегнать БД в тот же MySQL. Использование файл-серверных субд для web-а чревато серьёзными тормозами. А, расшаренный файл, это ещё и дыра в безопасности (ИМХО).

Comment: Дело в том, что программа работает уже несколько лет как раз с этой базой, а теперь решили сделать сайт

Comment: Это всё понятно. Только, как говорится, чудес не бывает...